# DevStack Installation Ubuntu Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-fWegjM/rcssmin/

Tags: devstack

During the installation process of devstack in Ubuntu using stack.sh , am having the error mentioned in ** below. Kindly share the solution if anyone figured out the way to do so.

```
2016-10-29 16:52:39.981 |       File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 111, in _add_defaults_data_files
****2016-10-29 16:52:39.982 |     TypeError: 'Documentation' object is not iterable****
2016-10-29 16:52:39.983 |     
2016-10-29 16:52:39.983 |     ----------------------------------------
****2016-10-29 16:52:40.548 | Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-fWegjM/rcssmin/
2016-10-29 16:52:40.974 | +inc/python:pip_install:1                  exit_trap****
2016-10-29 16:52:40.977 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:487                  local r=1
2016-10-29 16:52:40.982 | ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs -p
2016-10-29 16:52:40.988 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs=
2016-10-29 16:52:40.994 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:491                  [[ -n '' ]]
2016-10-29 16:52:40.997 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:497                  kill_spinner
2016-10-29 16:52:41.006 | +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:383               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2016-10-29 16:52:41.010 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:499                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
2016-10-29 16:52:41.015 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:500                  echo 'Error on exit'
2016-10-29 16:52:41.015 | Error on exit
2016-10-29 16:52:41.018 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:501                  generate-subunit 1477759430 531 fail
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the same issue as well. Looks like something broke upstream.

I was able to bypass the error by commenting out the else fragment in py36compat.py

It should help you run the stack.sh to completion but I don't know if it is wise to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to update everyone, the upstream issue has been resolved. No need to go through these steps anymore. Just update your devstack code base.

Answer (score 0):

@HassanPasha: thank you my friend, your solution work for me.

To elaborate:
Find that py36compat.py file, in my case was

sudo vim /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py

Scroll down to the ELSE statement (Line #111), comment out everything from line #111 -> #115

Save, quit, ./unstack.sh, reboot, sudo su stack, cd to whatever, ./stack.sh

Voila.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SSgd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not completely associated with the installation of DevStack but I've come across this thread while looking for the same error in the installation of another python module: django-compressor.

As stated above the problem lies in line #111 in py36compat.py file that is hidden somewhere in /lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages/setuptools/command/ directory. This part of code:

```
            else:
                # a (dirname, filenames) tuple
                dirname, filenames = item
                for f in filenames:
                    f = convert_path(f)
                    if os.path.isfile(f):
                        self.filelist.append(f)
```

should be replaced with something like this:

```
            else:
                filenames = item._files
                for f in filenames:
                    f = convert_path(f)
                    if os.path.isfile(f):
                        self.filelist.append(f)
```

Most likely this will be fixed by the developers soon, but maybe someone will benefit.